# Display data into x axis

Tags: python, bokeh

I m building a chart using bokeh. I have a line chart with lots of data. I need to see a portion of these on screen and then pan them with the pan tool.

This is the actual situation:
[image]

As you can see, there are data from Genuary to May, there are lots of data and it's all confusing.

I need to see only a portion of this data and then iterate through the data over time

This is the code:

```
plotSfera = figure(plot_width=int(850), plot_height=int(165), tools="pan,box_zoom,reset",
                               title=nomeSfera,
                               x_axis_type="datetime")
plotSfera.toolbar.logo = None
plotSfera.y_range.start = 0
plotSfera.line(x='DateTime', y='Valore', color="navy", alpha=1, source=sourceSfere)
```